# Granted permission applied to app when it restarted

Tags: android

I use below code to check permission:

```
if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                            getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS);
                    }
```

And by bellow code I catch result:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS){
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage(R.string.per_check_m);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }else {
                startActivityForResult(com.media_iran.android.iranama.Utils.ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(getActivity()), INTENT_REQUEST_GET_IMAGES);
            }
        }

    }
```

But when user accept permissions, it doesn't work and need to restart app and also clear it from app history to get permissions to work.

I found that it is a bug in android but in this way how other apps do this work?
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,this works perfect for me.
in OnCreate insert below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int hasWriteContactsPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);
            if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
```

Override onRequestPermissionResult:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted add code when permission granted.
                    signIn();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in your activity.

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called in your activity on your fragment.

Comment: I tried it on my activity that contains fragments but not work again

Comment: `requestPermissions()` is on your fragment but `onRequestPermissionsResult()` code should be in your activity.

Comment: I did all of them within AppCompactActivity but now work again

Comment: Can then problem from my phone? it os is custom CyanogemMod rom. android 23.

Comment: have you by debugging ? do you get control at onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: yes, but grandResult items is 0 when come in to onRequestPermissionsResult()